# Unupvote then downvote plus downvote on another question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19252/why-are-kingdom-halls-sometimes-built-in-the-quick-build-manner) was *un*upvoted and downvoted within the same hour. It has not been edited in over 60 days. I think this is weird because I thought that your vote was locked in after a day or two unless the post was edited. Can someone please clear this up?

Also [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19336/what-is-the-roman-catholic-stance-on-levitation) was downvoted within that same hour. I get very few downvotes and I think this sequence of events is very weird. I don't know what to make of this, but if the downvoter(s) see this meta post I would appreciate an explanation or a comment on the questions that were downvoted.

I also think that neither of these questions have any issues at all. They are not even hot topic sensitive issues and are about as close to objective questions with objective answers as is possible on this site.

Comment: I also got an unexpected downvote on my [women in Willow Creek leadership question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/how-did-the-willow-creek-church-come-to-allow-and-encourage-women-in-leadership). When I get an unexplained downvote I always [ask for an explanation](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/22973/how-did-the-willow-creek-church-come-to-allow-and-encourage-women-in-leadership#comment54744_22973) and leave it at that. If vote rigging / serial downvoting is going on, the SO team should be able to detect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question:

- Up- or down- votes are locked in 5 minutes after they're made: after 5 minutes a vote can't be changed...
- ...*unless* the post is edited.  Once a post is edited, any up- or down- vote is unlocked and **can be changed at any time.**
- But 5 minutes after a vote is changed, it'll be locked in again.

The idea is that if someone edits a question, it's almost like new (in terms of voting).  And since there's no notification to voters when a question is edited, it makes sense to leave it open for the original voter to come back any time and adjust their vote.

Comment: Take a look at the question I am talking about. It was last edited on September 27th. It was unupvoted only yesterday. It has been a bit longer than five minutes. Should I consider this a bug?

Comment: Not a bug... The question was asked 23 Sep and upvoted sometime before 27 Sep.  After the edit on the 27th, the vote was unlocked, and un-upvoted (yesterday, you said).

Comment: I get it now. The upvote that was removed must have been submitted before the most recent edit.